High Accuracy in PyTorch Handwritten Letter Model Fails During Web App Integration with React and FastAPI, Predicting Only 'r' or 'q' Consistently
I have developed a simple web application of handwritten english letters recognition, I have used pytorch for building the model which had a really high accuracy when tested, and then used react js and fast api to make a web app where you can draw the digit and get a prediction but It preformed so bad that I haven't got any prediction right...
I get mostly this two prediction: 'r' and 'q'
train.py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch.utils
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from PIL import Image
import pandas as pd
import os
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix, accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score, f1_score


model = torchvision.models.resnet18()
model.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 64, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(2, 2), padding=(3, 3), bias=False)
# model.features[0][0] = nn.Conv2d(
#     in_channels=1,  # Change input channels from 3 (RGB) to 1 (Grayscale)
#     out_channels=32,
#     kernel_size=(3, 3),
#     stride=(2, 2),
#     padding=(1, 1),
#     bias=False
# )
# model.features[0] = nn.Conv2d(1, 64, kernel_size=(11, 11), stride=(4, 4), padding=(2, 2))


# Create the model & hyperparameters    
# model = ResNet(ResBox)

## Load data

# label_map = {str(i): i for i in range(10)}
# label_map.update({chr(65 + i): 10 + i for i in range(26)})
# label_map.update({chr(97 + i): 36 + i for i in range(26)})


class CustomImageDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, csv_file, root_dir, transform=None):
        """
        Args:
            csv_file (string): Path to the CSV file with annotations (image paths and labels).
            root_dir (string): Directory with all the images.
            transform (callable, optional): Optional transform to be applied
                on a sample (image).
        """
        self.data_frame = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data_frame)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        img_name = os.path.join(self.root_dir, self.data_frame.iloc[idx, 0])
        image = Image.open(img_name)

        # Load the label (assuming the label is in the second column)
        label = self.data_frame.iloc[idx, 1]
        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)
        # print(label)
        return image, torch.tensor(label, dtype=torch.long)


# Example of using the dataset
transform = transforms.Compose(
    [
        transforms.Grayscale(num_output_channels=1),
        transforms.Resize((128, 128)),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.RandomRotation(degrees=(-30, 30)),
        transforms.Normalize(mean=0.485, std=0.229),  # Normalize
    ]
)
print("loading data...")
# Create dataset instance
train_dataset = CustomImageDataset(
    csv_file="./English_Dataset/train_dataset.csv",
    root_dir="./English_Dataset",
    transform=transform,
)
test_dataset = CustomImageDataset(
    csv_file="./English_Dataset/test_dataset.csv",
    root_dir="./English_Dataset",
    transform=transform,
)


train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)
test_dataloader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)

print("data loaded")
# hidden_size = 512
# num_classes = label_map.__len__()

# model = Cnn(hidden_size, num_classes)
# model = ResNet(ResBox)
# model.load_state_dict(torch.load("./model.pt"))
# print(model)


num_epochs = 5
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
loss_fct = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
losses = []
model.train()
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for idx, (image, label) in enumerate(train_dataloader):
        # forward pass
        output = model(image)
        loss = loss_fct(output, label)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        if (idx % 5) == 0:
            losses.append(loss.item())
            print(
                f"Epoch [{epoch+1}/{num_epochs}], Step [{idx}/{len(train_dataloader)}], Loss: {loss.item():.4f}"
            )

torch.save(model.state_dict(), "ResNet18.pt")


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(losses)
ax.grid()
fig.savefig("ResNet18_loss.png")

all_labels = []
all_predictions = []

with torch.no_grad():
    for data, label in test_dataloader:
        output = model(data)
        _, prediction = torch.max(output, 1)
        all_labels.extend(label.cpu().numpy())
        all_predictions.extend(prediction.cpu().numpy())

# Convert lists to numpy arrays
all_labels = np.array(all_labels)
all_predictions = np.array(all_predictions)

# Compute the accuracy
accuracy = accuracy_score(all_labels, all_predictions)
print(f'Accuracy: {accuracy:.4f}')

# Compute precision, recall, and F1-score
precision = precision_score(all_labels, all_predictions, average='weighted')
recall = recall_score(all_labels, all_predictions, average='weighted')
f1 = f1_score(all_labels, all_predictions, average='weighted')
print(f'Precision: {precision:.4f}')
print(f'Recall: {recall:.4f}')
print(f'F1 Score: {f1:.4f}')

# Generate a classification report
report = classification_report(all_labels, all_predictions)
print("Classification Report:\n", report)

# Compute the confusion matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(all_labels, all_predictions)
print("Confusion Matrix:\n", cm)

utils.py
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torchvision
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch import tensor as t
import numpy as np
import torch.nn.functional as F


def setup(model_path):

    model = torchvision.models.resnet18()
    model.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(
        1, 64, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(2, 2), padding=(3, 3), bias=False
    )
    # # model.features[0] = nn.Conv2d(1, 64, kernel_size=(11, 11), stride=(4, 4), padding=(2, 2))
    model.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_path, weights_only=True))
    return model


def transform(array):
    array = np.array(array, dtype=np.uint8)
    array = array.reshape((512, 512, 4))

    grayscale_array = array[:, :, 0]

    tensor_var = t(grayscale_array, dtype=torch.float32).unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0)
    tensor_var = 255 - tensor_var

    transform_pipeline = transforms.Compose(
        [
            transforms.Resize((128, 128)),  # Resize if necessary for model input
            # transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485], std=[0.229]),
        ]
    )

    tensor_var = transform_pipeline(tensor_var)
    return tensor_var


def predict(model, image: torch.Tensor):
    model.eval()
    outputs = model(image)
    probs = torch.softmax(outputs, dim=1)
    return probs


def get_output_dict(probabilities: torch.Tensor):
    label_map = {str(i): i for i in range(10)}
    label_map.update({chr(65 + i): 10 + i for i in range(26)})
    label_map.update({chr(97 + i): 36 + i for i in range(26)})
    inv_map = {v: k for k, v in label_map.items()}

    prob, prediction = torch.max(probabilities.flatten(), dim=0)

    prediction = inv_map[prediction.item()]

    return prediction

api.py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from pydantic import BaseModel
import utils
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import uvicorn
app = FastAPI()

model = utils.setup(model_path="./model/ResNet18.pt")



# Allow CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["http://localhost:8000"],  # React frontend origin
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],  
    allow_headers=["*"],  
)

# Pydantic model to define the structure of incoming data
class Item(BaseModel):
    data: list[int]

# Define route to receive data from React frontend
@app.post("/send-data")
def receive_data(item: Item):
    # print(len(received_data))
    received_data = item.data
    image = utils.transform(received_data)
    plt.imshow(image.view(128,128),cmap='gray')
    plt.show()
    output = utils.predict(model,image)
    print(output)
    # print(output) 
    # Send a response back to the React frontend
    prediction = utils.get_output_dict(output)
    return {"message": "Data received successfully", "received_data": received_data, "result": prediction}

# Run the application
if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="localhost", port=4000)


DrawingCanvas.jsx
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";

const DrawingCanvas = () => {
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  const [isDrawing, setIsDrawing] = useState(false);
  const [Prediction, setPrediction] = useState();
  // Start drawing
  const startDrawing = ({ nativeEvent }) => {
    const { offsetX, offsetY } = nativeEvent;
    const context = canvasRef.current.getContext("2d");
    context.strokeStyle = "white";
    context.lineWidth = 35;
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(offsetX, offsetY);
    setIsDrawing(true);
  };
  // Draw on canvas
  const draw = ({ nativeEvent }) => {
    if (!isDrawing) return;
    const { offsetX, offsetY } = nativeEvent;
    const context = canvasRef.current.getContext("2d");
    context.lineTo(offsetX, offsetY);
    context.stroke();
  };

  // Stop drawing
  const stopDrawing = () => {
    setIsDrawing(false);
  };

  // Get pixel data
  const sendData = async () => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    const imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    try {
      console.log(imageData.data);
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/send-data", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ data: Array.from(imageData.data) }),
      });

      const result = await response.json();
      console.log("Response from backend:", result);
      setPrediction(result.result);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error sending data:", error);
    }
  };
  // console.log(imageData.data);
  // alert("Pixel values have been logged to the console!");

  const clearCanvas = () => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // Clear the canvas
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <canvas
        ref={canvasRef}
        onMouseDown={startDrawing}
        onMouseMove={draw}
        onMouseUp={stopDrawing}
        onMouseLeave={stopDrawing}
        width="512 px"
        height="512 px"
        style={{ border: "1px solid white" }}
      />
      <br />
      <button onClick={sendData}>Get Result</button>
      <button onClick={clearCanvas}>Clear</button>
      <h2>The number is : {Prediction}</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DrawingCanvas;

App.jsx
import "./App.css";
import DrawingCanvas from "./DrawingCanvas";
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <DrawingCanvas/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


I have tried multiple architechtures, diffrent resolutions and still the same problem, I don't think the problem is in the model itselfe, the shape of the input data is correct beceause I have checked by ploting the image just before feeding it to the model for prediction

In the training transform, you normalized data before feeding them into your model, but when you transform the data received through React, you do not normalized them (the Normalize is commented in utils.transform())

I have tried with and without it... it didn't make a diffrencr
